# Ms Access Function MonthName causes crash

Tags: sql, ms-access, office365

In a query that has been working for years, i added the MonthName function so that i could eventually group by this value in a report. The part i added is this:

```
MonthName([WorkDate],False) AS Expr1
```

After adding it to the query, every time i run it, i get the results shown as normal, but as soon as i scroll over to see the newly added column, **Access crashes giving me NO ERROR MESSAGE and completely shuts down!**

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Customers.CustomerID, 
    tbl_Customers.CompanyName, 
    tbl_TimeSheet.WorkDate, 
    tbl_TimeSheet.TimeWorked, 
    tbl_Project.ProjectName AS Projekt, 
    tbl_TimeSheet.Description, 
    tbl_TimeSheet.Billable, 
    MonthName([WorkDate],False) AS Expr1
FROM 
    tbl_Customers INNER JOIN 
    (tbl_Project RIGHT JOIN tbl_TimeSheet ON tbl_Project.ConsProjectID = tbl_TimeSheet.ConsProjectID) 
    ON tbl_Customers.CustomerID = tbl_TimeSheet.CustomerID
ORDER BY 
tbl_TimeSheet.WorkDate;
```

**Has anyone encountered this behavior? Am I using the function wrong somehow or is this a bug in Access? What is the workaround?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `MonthName` has two arguments, `Month As Long` and `Abbreviate As Boolean`. Therefore, when you pass it a full date, it is the wrong datatype. Instead, you should use it in conjunction with the `Month` function:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_Customers.CustomerID, 
    tbl_Customers.CompanyName, 
    tbl_TimeSheet.WorkDate, 
    tbl_TimeSheet.TimeWorked, 
    tbl_Project.ProjectName AS Projekt, 
    tbl_TimeSheet.Description, 
    tbl_TimeSheet.Billable, 
    MonthName(Month([WorkDate]),False) AS Expr1
FROM 
    tbl_Customers INNER JOIN 
    (tbl_Project RIGHT JOIN tbl_TimeSheet ON tbl_Project.ConsProjectID = tbl_TimeSheet.ConsProjectID) 
ON tbl_Customers.CustomerID = tbl_TimeSheet.CustomerID
ORDER BY 
tbl_TimeSheet.WorkDate;
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even see that i was using the wrong data type... still, that Access crashes over this seems like a bug! Cheers!